Why is my 4digit 7segment display not showing all segments
My 4digit 7segment display is not showing all of the segments, the image is of it showing 8888. I have never used this display before and it has been lying around for a year or two does anyone know what happened, none of the resisters are touching eachother


Please draw a schematic of how the components are connected.

If this is being scanned (multiplexed) then say so. If not, there are not enough resistors there. When facing a problem, reduce it to the minimum possible to still illustrate the problem. In this case, I would say this means only enable ONE digit. And show the problem with just one. Prove there is a problem. No scanning/multiplexing. No CPU of any kind. Just power supply, resistors, and one display.

I see connections shorted. Even if they're no shorted, it's sloppy. And if you don't clean it up, you're forever going to have a bad time.  Also, it doesn't look like you have enough connections to illuminate the whole array even if your wiring was impeccable.

If you pop in the doctor's office and ask "hey doc! do I have a bowel cancer?", he/she can't answer by just looking at your face. Same thing here. Is the display common-anode or common-cathode? How do you drive it (Multiplexing or direct)? Show a schematic, show the code, show everything relevant.
